# React native firebase not show data in Release apk

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

```
buildToolsVersion = 32
minSdkVersion = 24
compileSdkVersion = 32
targetSdkVersion = 32

react-native = 0.68.1
@react-native-firebase/app   and   @react-native-firebase/firestore  = 15.1.1
Tested in Android 11 and 12. In android 11 work fine.
```

When getting the data from firebase/firestore, I save it in a state ([]) of type object.
When they are displayed in a  type tag or in a  they are not shown on the screen.
This only happens when the data is obtained from a release type apk, on emulated device everything works normal.

```
const [prods, setProds] = useState([]);
const [tipeprods, setTipeProds] = useState([]);
```

Function where i get my data

```
firestore().collection('Products').onSnapshot(querySnpshot => {
          const products = [];
          querySnpshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
            products.push(doc.data());
          });
          setProdFilter(products);
          setProds(products);
        });
```

Tag where I deploy my data

```
      <FlatList
        data={prodFilter}
        extraData={prodFilter}
        renderItem={productsAll}
        contentContainerStyle={{paddingHorizontal: 10, paddingBottom: 30}}
      />
```

Item where I drag my data

```
  const productsAll = ({item}) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          marginBottom: 20,
          elevation: 20,
        }}
        onPress={() => handlePress(item, 'ProdsScreen')}>
        <View
            style={{
                marginBottom: 10,
                width: '100%',
                backgroundColor: 'white',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                flexDirection: 'row',
                borderRadius: 20
            }}>
          <Image
            source={{uri: item.image}}
            resizeMode="cover"
            style={{width: '40%', height: 200, borderRadius: 20}}
          />
          <View
            style={{
              position: 'absolute',
              bottom: 0,
              height: 50,
              width: 80,
              backgroundColor: 'white',
              borderTopRightRadius: 20,
              borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
              alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center',
            }}>
            <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{item.volume}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontSize: 20,
            fontVariant: ['small-caps'],
            color: '#3C2B58',
          }}>
          {item.product_name}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };
```

Comment: Can you confirm, if you are able to fetch the data from firebase/firestore?

Comment: Yes, my data is shown in the log. @SandeepVokkareni